# Docker fails to enable php extensions

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, php-extension

I am trying to install some php extensions all day but an error I do not understand occurs. Basically if I remove the install `docker-php-ext-enable` line everything seems to work normally (except my app that depends on them).

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y unzip libcurl4-openssl-dev zlib1g-dev libpng-dev libxml2-dev libzip-dev


RUN a2enmod rewrite 
RUN docker-php-ext-enable bcmath gd mysqli soap zip xml ctype curl fileinfo json

COPY idoit-1.16.2.zip /temp/idoit-1.16.2.zip
RUN unzip /temp/idoit-1.16.2.zip -d /var/www
RUN rm /temp/idoit-1.16.2.zip

COPY apache-vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf


# RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www 

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]

EXPOSE 80
```

Here is what I get when i run `sudo docker build -t test .`

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  153.9MB
Step 1/23 : FROM php:8.0-apache
 ---> 1157b188bd87
Step 2/23 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y unzip libcurl4-openssl-dev zlib1g-dev libpng-dev libxml2-dev libzip-dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> aacd74715e3f
Step 3/23 : RUN a2enmod rewrite
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1ab1cd3d1228
Step 4/23 : RUN docker-php-ext-enable fileinfo
 ---> Running in 7d8a84075a50
error: 'fileinfo' does not exist

usage: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable [options] module-name [module-name ...]
   ie: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable gd mysqli
       /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable pdo pdo_mysql
       /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name 0-apc.ini apcu apc

Possible values for module-name:
opcache.so sodium.so

Some of the above modules are already compiled into PHP; please check
the output of "php -i" to see which modules are already loaded.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you remove enabling the `fileinfo` module and any others that give errors(just the ones that give errors), what sort of errors do you get from your application?

Comment: I get the same error for every module, I even tried to create a separate RUN line for each

Comment: OK, so if you remove them all, what errors do you get form your application?

Comment: My app needs them to run. I get the message `Not all needed extensions are installed. I need: mysqli xml standard pcre session I have: xml standard pcre session`

Comment: That error does not really make sense, but its clear something is not working as far as these extensions are concerned

Comment: Try `RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli`

Comment: Wow, well, this did not throw an error. Things are quite better now!!! I only get `PHP GD Extension: Not found ERROR` and `PHP PDO_MySQL Extension: Not found. Needed for database abstraction ERROR` as far as extensions are concerned. Will try them independently